# Saving Frozen EfficientNetB0 in Tensorflow 2.x fails due to custom gradients

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, efficientnet

I'm fine tuning an EfficientNetB0 model (from Keras Applications in TF 2.9.2) and I want to optimize the final model as much as possible in order to be inferred via Tensorflow C++ API. Applying `tf.saved_model.save` after `tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants.convert_variables_to_constants_v2` works fine for several architectures such as MobileNet or ResNet50, but fails for EfficientNetBX family.

As a minimal code that illustrates the described problem, the following yields the expected results:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import convert_variables_to_constants_v2

input_shape = (224, 224, 3)

model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=True, input_shape=input_shape)
#model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(weights='imagenet', include_top=True, input_shape=input_shape)

full_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))
full_model = full_model.get_concrete_function(tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape,
                                                            model.inputs[0].dtype,
                                                            name='yourInputName'))
frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(full_model)

tf.saved_model.save(frozen_func, 'saved_model')
```

...but fails when switching to EfficientNetB0. More precisely, it throws the following error:

> ValueError: Found invalid capture
> Tensor("efficientnetb0/stem_activation/beta:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) when saving custom gradients

I would like to know if I am missing any particular step that is required for EfficientNetB0, or if it is a keras/tensorflow bug. In the later case, is there any workaround I can apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug that appeared in  TF 2.10 and hasn't been solved as of TF 2.12.

For what is worth, `EfficientNetV2`s don't have this issue (tested on TF 2.12).